# C++11 regex_replace weird behaviour

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

Can somebody please explain to me why this code results in the output below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    std::string test_string("foo.bar.baz.<name>:<value>|@<rate>|#tag:<tag>");

    if (std::regex_match(test_string, std::regex(".*(<name>).*"))) {
        std::cout << "MATCH!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "NO MATCH!" << std::endl;
    }

    test_string = std::regex_replace(test_string, std::regex(".*(<name>).*"), "master");
    std::cout << test_string << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[root@88c9be66f008 tmp]# ./test 
MATCH!
master
```

It seems to me that the runtime is broken. Searched for regex on the below page, nothing is implemented.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011

Answer (score 0):

`regex_replace` doesn't modify its argument, it returns a new string. Try this:

```
test_string = std::regex_replace(test_string, std::regex(".*(<name>).*"), "master");
```

Comment: doesnt't work. It kills the whole string: [root@0be8f48dd8d3 /]# ./test 
MATCH!
master

Comment: Well, you tell it to replace "something, followed by <name>, following by something else" with "master". If you just want to replace "<name>", use only that as the regex. C++ doesn't have a "replace only this submatch" functionality.

Comment: good point. I was confused that the regex_replace uses the match for identify the string to replace. It makes sense now. Thanks!